# How to use alt=media with Google Drive Python API?

Tags: python, google-drive-api

Here is one way (based on Google Drive Python quickstart.py) to download a file from Google Drive with the Python API:

```
credentials = get_credentials()
http = credentials.authorize(httplib2.Http())
service = discovery.build('drive', 'v2', http=http)

request = service.files().get_media(fileId=file_id)
fh = io.FileIO(file_name, 'wb')
downloader = MediaIoBaseDownload(fh, request, chunksize=1024*1024)

done = False
while done is False:
    status, done = downloader.next_chunk()
    if status:
        print("download progress: {} %".format(int(status.progress() * 100)))
print("download complete!")
```

This writes the Drive file with file ID *file_id* to a local file with name *file_name*.

However, the [documentation](https://developers.google.com/drive/v2/reference/files/get) says over and over that the "preferred method" is to use "alt=media".

How does alt=media work with files().get() ?  Where does alt=media go?  What does it do?

Can anyone provide a simple example of how to download a file with files().get() and alt=media?

Or... does "use *files().get()* with *alt=media*" just mean use *files().get_media()* ?!

Thanks to anyone who can provide a clear explanation!

Comment: The parameter alt=media goes in the url, and you would use it if you are calling directly the API. In your case, the python library is taking care of the url and the necessary parameters, in this case "alt=media". To understand how things are done, you should call the API directly with a different tool. Try using the OAuth Playground where you will have to set most of the parameter for the desired request. https://developers.google.com/oauthplayground/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Gerardo's comment is apt and basically what I suspected.  Case closed.  And thank you for pointing out the OAuth Playground.